# Golang random "unexpected EOF" error with reading multipart.Part

Tags: go, file-upload

Code below handles one or more files uploaded with enctype="multipart/form-data", typically from a web-page. We can assume, form parts are always files.

```
// Error handling not complete
func (t *Tools) UploadFiles(r *http.Request, uploadDir string) {
    reader, _ := r.MultipartReader()
    for {
        part, err := reader.NextPart()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            return
        }

        fileName := part.FileName()
        var outfile *os.File
        defer outfile.Close()
        if outfile, err := os.Create(filepath.Join(uploadDir, fileName)); err != nil {
            return
        } else {
            fileSize, err := io.Copy(outfile, part)
            log.Printf("Size: %d FileName: %s Error: %v\n", fileSize, fileName, err)
            if err != nil {
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When multiple files are uploaded **io.Copy** in the code above at times returns **unexpected EOF** error.

- It never happens when a single file is uploaded. It kind-of starts happening when number of files uploaded are more than 20. Each file is roughly 1 MB in size.

It never happens when we use **r.ParseMultipartForm**, **r.MultipartForm.File** and then use **io.Copy(outfile, header.Open())** where header is **value** in the Hashmap returned by **r.MultipartForm.File**

Can anyone point out what can be going wrong?

**go version go1.20 darwin/amd64**

~Nathan

Comment: Perhaps this is related to the http request timing out? You could test this hypothesis by copying the parts into memory before writing any of them to the disk, since writing to memory is much faster.

Comment: @TrevorKropp Thanks for your reply. Actually, everything is running on local machine and upload of 40 files, when it works, also happens under 3 seconds. So this shouldn't be request timeout issue. I did try first copying it to a in-memory buffer before writing to a file, but it didn't help. This is similar to what standard library  function 'func (r *Reader) readForm(maxMemory int64) (_ *Form, err error) {' from file *formdata.go* does. Of course, it does much more.

Comment: Does it fail deterministically, i.e., on the same part for repeated uploads of the same content? Does it fail on the first byte or somewhere in the middle of the part?

Comment: With the original code, error is non-deterministic. For instance, for the error printed  **Size: 658047 FileName: abcd.png Error: unexpected EOF**, actual file size is 1690270 bytes. But it got an EOF after reading 658047 bytes. For some other run when you upload exactly the same set of files, it only read 530862 bytes before throwing EOF error whereas file size is 644930 bytes. I am uploading exact same 39 files always, typically first 20 files are saved correctly and then error occurs randomly for some file. For sure, in some cases, all 39 files get saved correctly without any errors.

Comment: It looks like that error can pop up from either reading or writing. On the reading side, if there's an issue parsing the multipart stuff, it may emit that an unexpected EOF error. I wouldn't expect that to be intermittent though. On the writing side, if the OS refuses to write more bytes, it will also emit that error. Perhaps you should write your own copy logic to nail down which side is giving that error to narrow things.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use `websocket` to do such thing because you never know how many files there will be and request may be much longer then you expect.
This kind of programs may not give errors on local machine but may give on server.

What you can do is when user submits form you can handle that click event with `javascript` and open a `websocket` connection and upload files one by one and show progress to user that how many files are uploaded

here is a javascript code for uploading one file to server via websocket connection you can change it according to your need actually i was uploading excel file to do the entry in database and the records in excelsheet were more then 50000 so i was also sending the progress from server also.

```
<form>
    <input type="File" name="catalogues" id="catalogues">
    <input type="button" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="SendFile()">
</form>

function SendFile(){
    console.clear()
    start = performance.now();
    const Socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:1323/api/v1/catalogue/upload/ws");

    Socket.onopen=function() {
        //authentication
        Socket.send("<Authentication Token>")
        Socket.binaryType="arraybuffer"
        let XlsxFile = document.getElementById('catalogues').files[0];
        Socket.send(XlsxFile)
    };
    Socket.onmessage = function (evt) {
        if(typeof evt.data=="object"){
            const link = document.createElement('a');
            const XlsxFile = new Blob([evt.data], {type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'});
            link.setAttribute('href', URL.createObjectURL(XlsxFile))
            link.setAttribute('download', `response.xlsx`);
            link.innerText="Download"
            document.body.append(link)
            end = performance.now();
            timeTaken = end - start;
            console.log("Function took " +
                timeTaken + " milliseconds");
        }
        console.log(evt.data)
    };

    Socket.onclose = function() {
        // websocket is closed.
        console.log("Connection is closed...");
    };
    Socket.onerror = function(e) {

        console.log(e);

    };
}
```

what you should do on the server side is upgrade the connection to websocket and do the authentication via whichever authentication method you use and then handle the files one by one

```
for {
    mt, message, err := ws.ReadMessage()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errorx.WrapDefaultError(err.Error())
    }
    
    if mt != websocket.BinaryMessage {
        ws.WriteMessage(ws.TextMessage,[]byte("Invalid Message Type : " + string(message)))
        break
    }
}
```

then you can read those bytes and write it to file to do the work

the one thing is you need to do this thing in go routine because server connection will be closed but websocket connection will be persistent

you can use [gorilla websocket](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket) library to do your work easily
this library is archived but it works perfectly also there is no good options other then that